Why does the image classification model perform worse when augmenting only minority class
I have a problem of data imbalance (1:10 ratio) for image classification tasks.
To cope with it, I tried different imbalance training strategies, including weighted loss function, different loss functions, weighted random sampler, data augmentation, etc..
I tried the combination stain augmentation (as it is histopathology patches) only on minority class and weighted random sampler, so that augmented data from minority class is sampled with an equal amount as majority class. I implemented this based on the suggestion in this url. However, as you can see in the  Loss and metric curve; blue - augmentation only on minority class, pink - augmentation on both classes, this strategy seems to work better initially, and then the performance drastically decreases later on in the training.
I am wondering why this happens and would be helpful if you have any idea on how to train and evaluate the model on highly imbalanced data.
Combination of augmentation on minority class and weighted random sampler, and it seems to perform worse..

Welcome to Cross Validated! The class imbalance and classification metrics links in my profile should be of interest to you.

Unbalanced classes are almost certainly not a problem, and oversampling, undersampling or weighting will not solve this non-problem:
Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?
And this Meta.CV thread contains a curated list of useful links on imbalanced data.
